# Multiple javascript counters on page

Tags: javascript, counter

My code is below.

I want to have several of the counters shown e.g. Counter #1, Counter #2 etc.

I was wondering if there is a better way than having to repeat the script as many times. In other words, having one script that each different counter can call, if that makes sense.

Thanks!

```js
const countBtn = document.querySelector('.countBtn button')
let countNum = document.querySelector('.countNum div')
let downBtn = document.querySelector('.downBtn button')
let resetBtn = document.querySelector('.resetBtn button')

countBtn.addEventListener('click', countUp);
downBtn.addEventListener('click', countDown);
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', reset);

function countUp(){
 countNum.innerHTML ++;
}

function countDown(){
 countNum.innerHTML --;
}


function reset(){
 countNum.innerHTML = 0;
}
```

```css
div{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
button{
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.countNum{
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 border: solid gray;
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 5px 0 0 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.counter{
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 font-size: 2rem;
 background-color: rgb(221, 5, 5);
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 0;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: left;
 border-radius: 10px;
 width: 60%;
}
.counter button{
 height: 45px;
 width: 45px;
 margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='counter'>
 <div class='downBtn'>
  <button>-</button>
 </div>
 <div class='resetBtn'>
  <button>R</button>
 </div>
 <div class='catagory'>
  <div>Counter #1</div>
 </div>
 <div class = 'countNum'>
  <div> 0 </div>
 </div>
 <div class='countBtn'>
  <button>+</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now that I'm done editing your question, here's a simple tip: You already use functions. Instead of directly targeting `countNum` inside those functions, use a parameter. Like `function countUp(elem){ elem.innerHTML ++; }`. Then change your event listeners to: `some_button.addEventListener('click', function(){ countUp(target_element)}, false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple ways to implement that, and this here is one of them

```js
function setupCounter(counter) {
  const countBtn = counter.querySelector('.countBtn button')
  let countNum = counter.querySelector('.countNum div')
  let downBtn = counter.querySelector('.downBtn button')
  let resetBtn = counter.querySelector('.resetBtn button')

  countBtn.addEventListener('click', countUp);
  downBtn.addEventListener('click', countDown);
  resetBtn.addEventListener('click', reset);

  function countUp() {
    countNum.innerHTML++;
  }

  function countDown() {
    countNum.innerHTML--;
  }


  function reset() {
    countNum.innerHTML = 0;
  }
}
const firstCounter = document.querySelector('div.counter')
setupCounter(firstCounter)

function addCounter(category, parent = document.body) {
  const clone = firstCounter.cloneNode(true)
  clone.querySelector('div.category').innerText = category
  parent.appendChild(clone)
  
  setupCounter(clone)
}

addCounter(`Custom Name`)
addCounter(`God bless 'Merica`)

for (let i=2; i <= 3; i++) {
  addCounter(`Counter ${i}`)
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.countNum {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: solid gray;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.counter {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: rgb(221, 5, 5);
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 60%;
}

.counter button {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='counter'>
    <div class='downBtn'>
      <button>-</button>
    </div>
    <div class='resetBtn'>
      <button>R</button>
    </div>
    <div class='category'>
      <div>Counter #1</div>
    </div>
    <div class='countNum'>
      <div> 0 </div>
    </div>
    <div class='countBtn'>
      <button>+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<body>
```

Comment: Thanks that is great. Would there be a way to name each of the counters e.g. "MyFirstCatagory/Counter, MySecondCatagory/Counter" etc. since I eventually want to have another script that will take the current count of each counter and perhaps store them in an array.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, I've just updated the code to receive the name as a parameter, check it out. If that answer suffices, please accept it as the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

you can implement the revealing module pattern which looks like:

```js
function Counter(defaultValue) {
  var root = document.createElement('div');
  var inc = document.createElement('button');
  var dec = document.createElement('button');
  var display = document.createElement('span');
  
  inc.innerText = '+';
  dec.innerText = '-';
  
  root.appendChild(display);
  root.appendChild(inc);
  root.appendChild(dec);
  
  
  inc.addEventListener('click', add);
  dec.addEventListener('click', subtract);
  
  function getRoot() {
   return root;
  }
  
  function add() {
   defaultValue++;
   render();
  }
  
  function subtract() {
   defaultValue--;
   render();
  }
  
  function render() {
   display.innerText = defaultValue;
  }
  
  render();
  
  return {
    getRoot: getRoot,
    add: add,
    subtract: subtract
  }
  
}

var wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
 wrapper.appendChild(Counter(0).getRoot());
})
```

```html
<button>Add counter</button>

<div id="wrapper">

</div>
```

Comment: That code works great thanks, but I need something a little different, sorry for the confusion. I'm going to have about 7 counters "hard coded" into the html. In other words, something like shown below. Instead of having 7 different versions of the same script, I was trying to figure out how I can set it up to make it more efficient.
```
<div id="counter_01">
  ..  Counter #1 ..
</div>
<div id="counter_02">
       .. Counter #2 ..
 </div>
<div id="counter_03">
   .. Counter #3 ..
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 7 counters?

Comment: They are counters for retail sales at point of purchase, counting cross-sells and up-sells per transaction. For example, the first counter will be named "widgets". When the cashier sells a widget in a transaction, they just hit the plus button to up the count by 1. The second counter will be named "badges". When the cashier sells a badge in a transaction, they count that. And so on. Then I'll put a "total" button for example and their scores are recorded. That's about it.. Eventually I'll have a function to count the percentages e.g.  widgets were sold on 20% of the transactions.