# Rendering counters with forEach (EJS and JS)

Tags: javascript, foreach, rendering, ejs, addeventlistener

I have to make a homepage with EJS that has product cards with a counter  attached to a cart button. I'm currently working on the counter which has two buttons (minus and plus) and a span where a number is inserted through JS. Both buttons have respective classes (".minusButton" and ".plusButton") and my empty span also has ".counterNumber" as a class attribute. I also need to disable the minus button when the counter number is 1, and I have to do the same for the plus button once the number gets to 10.

I created a JS file to work on the counter in my *public* folder and started my job by getting their classes using querySelectorAll.

```
let minus = document.querySelectorAll(".minusButton")
let plus = document.querySelectorAll(".plusButton")
let numQuantity = document.querySelectorAll(".counterNumber")
```

I also declare the default value of my product counter. This is then inserted in the empty span on my front page.

```
let counter = 1
```

My problem starts right here after doing this. If I use just *querySelector* only my first card will listen to the events written on this script, so I choose *querySelectorAll* to catch all of them in an array so I can use forEach. My question is: Which is the correct way to loop through this array using this method?

This is what I tried to do.

Firstly, due to the default value of my counter number being 1, I wanted to create a function where my minus button is already disabled until that number increases.

```
function disableBegins(){
    if(counter==1){
        minus.forEach((min)=>{
            min.toggleAttribute("disabled")
            min.classList.add("disabled-counter-button")
        })
    }
}
```

Then the function I use to write the counter's number in my document:

```
function showCounter(){
    numQuantity.forEach((num)=>{
        num.innerHTML=counter
    })
}
```

My main functions:

```
function disableMinus(){
    if(counter<=1){
        minus.forEach((min)=>{
            min.toggleAttribute("disabled")
            min.classList.toggle("disabled-counter-button")
        })
    }else if(counter>1){
        minus.forEach((meno)=>{
            min.removeAttribute("disabled")
            min.classList.remove("disabled-counter-button")
        })
        plus.forEach((plu)=>{
            plu.removeAttribute("disabled")
            plu.classList.remove("disabled-counter-button")
        })
    }
    showCounter()
}

function disablePlus(){
    if(counter>=10){
        plus.forEach((plu)=>{
            plu.toggleAttribute("disabled")
            plu.classList.toggle("disabled-counter-button")
        })
    }else if(counter<10){
        plus.forEach((ma)=>{
            plu.removeAttribute("disabled")
            plu.classList.remove("disabled-counter-button")
        })
        minus.forEach((min)=>{
            min.removeAttribute("disabled")
            min.classList.remove("disabled-counter-button")
        })
    }
    showCounter()
}

showCounter()
disableBegins()
```

And finally my listeners:

```
minus.forEach((min)=>{
    min.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        counter--
        disableMinus()
    })
})

plus.forEach((plu)=>{
    plu.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        counter++
        disablePlus()
    })
})
```

The counter number was successfully written in all of my span tags and the buttons and functions worked correctly, but once I tested my code on this homepage I realized I still had problems because all of the counters were connected. If I click on just one button, all of the numbers change although I didn't click on them. I know this is obviously related to the forEach method but I can't find a solution.

How can I make all of my counters react separately to these events? (Using only EJS and JS) Is there any problem related to the functions?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You have only declared a single counter, and your `showCounter` function loops through every element and updates them to display that single value. To have separate values you will need a counter for *each* element and only update that one element when it's plus or minus button is clicked.

Comment: see: [Multiple javascript counters on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61901400/multiple-javascript-counters-on-page)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is easier to make counters with their own state and unified logic through classes.

The class constructor turns out to be cumbersome due to working with the DOM tree (creating elements), but each such counter is guaranteed to have its own state and does not depend on the external environment.

```js
class Counter {
  #nums = 1; // begin counter
  #btnMin = document.createElement('button');
  #btnMax = document.createElement('button');
  #val = document.createElement('span');
  constructor() {
    // create conteiner
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('counter')
    // init buttons
    this.#btnMin.disabled = true;
    this.#btnMin.innerText = '-';
    this.#btnMax.innerText = '+';
    // add listeners
    this.#btnMin.addEventListener('click', this.minus.bind(this));
    this.#btnMax.addEventListener('click', this.plus.bind(this));
    // pack it in a container
    div.appendChild(this.#btnMin)
    div.appendChild(this.#val);
    div.appendChild(this.#btnMax)
    // render in DOM
    document.getElementById('counters').appendChild(div);
    this.render();
  }

  minus() {
    this.#nums--;
    if (this.#nums === 1) {
      this.#btnMin.disabled = true;
    }
    if (this.#btnMax.disabled) this.#btnMax.disabled = false;
    this.render()
  }

  plus() {
    this.#nums++;
    if (this.#nums === 10) {
      this.#btnMax.disabled = true;
    }
    if (this.#btnMin.disabled) this.#btnMin.disabled = false;
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    this.#val.innerText = this.#nums.toString();
  }
}

// run
new Counter();
new Counter();
new Counter();
```

```css
.counter {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="counters"></div>
```